# TFS - Asking for Credential Every time

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I'm using Vs2013 and TFS for my project.

I have to run my VS in admin mode because of some reason but it ask me TFS credential every time when i start vs.

I'm tired of being provide it every time.

Is there any workaround so that TFS will connect automatically without asking credential every time.

Note: I logged as Normal user and running VS in admin mode by using "Run as".

Answer (score 0):

If you log into your local machine with the same credentials as you are trying to connect to TFS you will get automatic ostrich with active directory. The fact that it is asking for credentials at all is unusual in an active directory configuration. If you are logging into another domain with credentials that are not the same as your local ones then use the windows credential store to save the credentials for the TFS server name or domain name.